# Problem in fetching data from different port in react-

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to fetch the data and display on browser but getting an error '**notes.map is not a function**'.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Note as NoteModel } from './models/note';
import NoteComponent from './component/NoteComponent';

function App() {
  const [notes, setNotes] = useState<NoteModel[]>([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadNotes = async () => {
      try {
        setIsLoading(true);
        const response = await fetch("/api/notes", { method: "GET" });
        const notes : [] = await response.json();
        setNotes(notes);
        console.log(notes);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        alert(error);
      } finally {
        setIsLoading(false); 
      }
    };
    loadNotes();
  },[]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {
        notes.map(note => (
          <NoteComponent note={note} key={note._id}/>
        ))
      }
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I am able to display data through 'JSON.stringyfy(notes)' but i want display data in component.

Comment: When you do `JSON.stringyfy(notes)` is it an object or an array? <br>
Maybe you get object like this `{ notes: [...]}` from your API and you first have to extract your array from the object